# Class inheritance versus Interface inheritance

Tags: theory, metrics, code-metrics

What is the difference between the Class inheritance and Interface inheritance? What of the above yields a lower coupling and a higher cohesion..

Answer (score 0):

Class inheritance is more of a `is a`, so `Square` is a `Shape` whereas Interface is more of `has the ability of`, so `Square` has the ability of `Resizable`. But as you say you can couple multiple abilities using interface inheritance.